# Delete a record from a list in Java

Tags: java

This is my code for deleting a record from a list but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
public void deleteRecord (Scanner in)
{
    int delete = 0;

    showRecords();
    System.out.println("Enter the number in the list to delete:");
    delete = in.nextInt();
    delete = delete -1;
    for (int i = delete; i < this.size; i++)
    {
        this.collection[i] = this.collection[i + 1];
        this.collection[size] = null;
        this.size--;
        System.out.println("Record deleted successfully");
        showRecords();
    }
    System.out.println("Please enter a number in the list to delete");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean - "I can;t seem to get it to work" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are decreasing the `size` too many times. It should be done only once after you moved the elements in the `for` loop.

Also look out for the `for` loop condition. Since you are using `i + 1` inside the loop you can only loop until `i < size - 1` or you will attempt to access elements outside of the array size.

```
int toDelete = in.nextInt(); // assume it's between 0 and size - 1
for (int i = toDelete; i < size - 1; i++) {
    collection[i] = collection[i + 1];
} 
collection[size] = null;
size--;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're obligated to use array operations to do the work, and in that case, @KarolDowbecki's answer both identifies the main issue and provides a good solution.

Personally, though, I would avoid the loop altogether by using `System.arraycopy()`:

```
System.arraycopy(this.collection, deletionIndex, this.collection, deletionIndex + 1,
        this.size - (deletionIndex + 1));
this.size--;
```

Shorter code tends to mean fewer errors, and that particular code is at least as clear as the original loop, at least to me.  Also, without a loop, there's no opportunity to put statements into the loop that don't belong there, which is the main problem with the original code.